# filemaker :: script doesn't find absolute pathed file

Tags: import, path, filemaker

I try to import data from files inside a folder. herefor I mad ea script thats first imports all files from the folder and reads their paths. then I try to import these files and its data one after another.

my problem now is that FM tells me that it could not find the specified file at the place the path is leading to, but the file is there and the path is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out that you need to write "filemac:/" instead "file://"...